# How to iterate JSON in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm creating the JSON string in PHP, and using AJAX to fetch it.

```
<?php 
// for loop {
    $contacts[] = array(
        'firstname' => $contact->getFname(),
        'lastname' => $contact->getLname(),
        'address' => $contact->getAddress(),
        'city' => $contact->getCity(),
        'postcode' => $contact->getPostcode()
    ); 
// } end for loop

$arr = array('success' => 'yes', 'con' => $contacts);
echo json_encode($arr);
exit;
?>
```

I am not able to iterate a JSON string in Javascript. I have tried using the `for loop`, but I'm unable to get the results

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.con.length; i++) {
    alert(d[i]);
}
```

I want to iterate through each con array in Ajax success function. My code is not working.

Comment: @MattWhipple it is clearly written that  This for loop is not working in javascrit function

Comment: why this question is voted down ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this:

```
function(data) {
        // This for loop is not working
        for (var i = 0; i < data.con.length; i++) {
            alert(d[i]);
        }
```

be something like this:

```
function(data) {
        // This for loop is not working
        for (var i = 0; i < data.con.length; i++) {
            alert(data.con[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `.each`

```
success:  function(data) {  
 $.each(data, function(key, val){
   alert(key+" - "+val);
 });   
}
```

Comment: i want to interate only con array

Comment: @shail try data.con in each loop